# Laravel custom redirect if user is not logged in?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have on my project route groups for 4 subdomains, on one subdomain I set 'middleware' => 'auth', it works, but if guest try to access this protected subdomain he is redirected to ***sub***.project.com/login and not to *project.com/login*, where can I set it correctly?

Comment: Let's see your code.

Comment: include here the code you started.

Comment: @ammezie which code do you need? I have custom controller as "AuthController", there I have following functions: getLogin(), postLogin() and getLogout(), on main domain login and redirect works... my middleware code is there: http://pastebin.com/LtEbc4D9

Comment: change this in your auth middleware create a route and use redirect().

Comment: just go to your AuthController and change the `$redirectTo` you can also allowed other routes by adding in `['except' => ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to handle the redirect within the middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($request->getPort() != 80 || Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        //to account for json or ajax requests 
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson())
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
        return redirect('auth/login')->withErrors(['must login']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it shouldn't be a problem. On *by default* I mean, you had to explicitly tell Laravel where to redirect, if you didn't do so (didn't alter middleware logic in any way), there are 3 things that come in play:

- Your `.htaccess` (or httpd.conf) is messed up.
- Certificate issues. Do you have SSL enabled on the login page? If the website config file points to a cert issued for not the same domain, it causes such problems.
- `config/app.php` includes the wrong domain

(It's a stupid question on my part, but could you please confirm that it **redirects to** and not **renders** the content available on that subdomain? To exclude some possibilities.)